# Does google contact sync also sync the sim card or does it just sync the contacts stored on the phone?

Tags: samsung, 6.0-marshmallow, backup, samsung-galaxy-s-5, google-backup

So I have this old Galaxy S5 phone that that I'm upgrading to a samsung a51, and I'm also getting a new SIM card that keeps the phone number but doesn't keep the contacts. Do i need to do something extra or does it just work? Or should I use Samsung smart switch?

Comment: Google Contacts is just one of the contact source and it isn't related to SIM contacts at all. It is the Contacts app that is responsible for importing and managing contacts from multiple contact sources like SIM card, Google Contacts, etc. However, I don't have experience with Samsung Smart Switch, so I can't really comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments by Andrew T said, you have a few storage options:

1. SIM card.
2. Phone.
3. Google account.

During the saving of the contact, it should give you the option to choose, or there should be a default setting.